# What to download using pacman while Installing arch linux?

Tags: linux, arch-linux

Do we need to download all the packages like bash,vi,etc using pacman in order to run arch-chroot command while installing arch?

Comment: you install the "base" package in order to install basic packages like pacman, bash, vi as text editor,... arch-chroot changes the root **and starts a shell on that system.** how can you do that without having a shell installed?

Comment: Arch-chroot is not working...i have run the command pacman -i .......after that i installed nothing from the list

Comment: as the beginner guide says, `pacman` is for a running system, it installs software onto the root system. what you have done via `pacman` was installing the base system onto your install disk. you have to use `pacstrap` instead. **please read the beginner guide**

Comment: Ok....but packstrap is giving a list of packages......is there any package that must be downloaded to run arch-chroot command............because if iam not downloading any package the arch-chroot command is not running

Comment: You have to install everything that pacstrap wants you to install. It's the basic system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You install the base system with the command `pacstrap -i /mnt base` suppose you have mounted the root partition to `/mnt`. In order to successfully `arch-chroot` into that partition and continue with the installation. It creates the directory structure and install basic software to run a system. You need to atleast download any shell... bash is just the default. if you want to use an other shell, for example zsh, you can also use `pacstrap -i /mnt base zsh` and `chroot` into `/mnt` by providing a parameter with the shell you want to use.

Have a look at the beginners guide: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners'_guide

`arch-chroot` is a installation script that is supposed to aid you. I is part of the `arch-install-scripts` package. It is preinstalled on the booting medium you are using. It won't be installed on the system that you use have mounted to install to.